# Pandas - subtring a column where position number in separate column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

**Dataset**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,3,4], 'b': ['0101010', '0100010', '0111100']})
```

Basically trying to create a column where it takes the substring of length 1 of column `b` starting at position number in column `a`

**Attempt**

```
position = df['a']
df['c'] = df['b'].str[position]
```

**Desired Output**

```
a    b        c
0    0101010  0
3    0100010  0
4    0111100  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `zip`:

```
df['c'] = [b[a] for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b)]
```

Or [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b'][x['a']], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   a        b  c
0  0  0101010  0
1  3  0100010  0
2  4  0111100  1
```

Performance is different:

```
#[3000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [236]: %timeit df['c'] = [b[a] for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b)]
557 µs ± 25.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [237]: %timeit df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b'][x['a']], axis=1)
57.3 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```